# Azure AD: Fetch Tenant ID using Client Details

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any method to fetch the Tenant ID, from an Azure app's client ID and Client Secret?

I know, if we have user credentials, we can directly use the login.microsoftonline.com/common endpoint.

Is there any similar endpoint, while trying to get an access token using the Client ID and Client Secret only, or is there anyway, using which, I can get the tenant ID, from the client ID and Client Secret, so that I can dynamically create the auth endpoint URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that since you already have the client id and client secret, you should be an internal user of the tenant. In this case, you can log in to Azure Portal directly to view the tenant id.

If you don't want to use this method, then you can use the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I know you don't have the tenant id, so you can specify the `{tenant}` as `abc.onmicrosoft.com`.

Then you can get the access token. Decode the access token in https://jwt.io/, you will find a `tid` claim, which is the tenant id.

Please note if you also don't know the domain name, getting the tenant id is **impossible and unreasonable**. It means you are not the internal user of this tenant, getting the access token is not safe for that tenant.